# XSLT Selecting and merging nodes based off content

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

Sorry if a similar question has been asked already, I am quite new to xsl and couldn't find a suitable answer.

I am trying to transform an XML to another XML file. The problem is, in the input xml the only nodes I have are `<p>` elemements. I have to take the text content of these elements and  make new nodes out of them and merge some others to new nodes. The secind problem is, there is no real consistency in the input xml. I am really stumped.

(The input XML I am working on is longer than the example given, but it follows the same pattern: one div with page class and two contents and paragraphs per div)

The input xml:

```
<root>
    <div class="page">
        <p>Content:</p>
        <p>This is the content. </p>
        <p>Content continues. </p>
        <p>End content.</p>
        <p>Paragraph:</p>
        <p>◼ Beginning of new paragraph. </p>
        <p>End of new paragraph.</p>
        <p>◼ New line here.</p>
        <p>Content:</p>
        <p>Heres lies the second content </p>
        <p>Continiuation of the second content. </p>
        <p>Second content ends.</p>
        <p>Paragraph:</p>
        <p>◼ Start of second paragraph. </p>
        <p>Finish of second paragraph.</p>
        <p>◼ This should also be separate.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="page">
        <p>Content:</p>
        <p>Third content starts here. </p>
        <p>Third content continues. </p>
        <p>End content three.</p>
        <p>Paragraph:</p>
        <p>◼ Beginning of third paragraph. </p>
        <p>End of third paragraph.</p>
        <p>◼ And again a new line.</p>
    </div>
</root>
```

The output I am trying to get is this:

```
<root>
    <page>
        <title>Content:<title>
        <content>This is the content. Content continues. End content.<content>
        <paragraph>Paragraph:<paragraph>
        <pcontent>◼ Beginning of new Paragraph. End of new Paragraph.</pcontent>
        <pcontent>◼ New line here.</pcontent>
        <title>Content:<title>
        <content>This is the second content. Second content continues. End content two.<content>
        <paragraph>Paragraph:<paragraph>
        <pcontent>◼ Beginning of second Paragraph. End of second Paragraph.</pcontent>
        <pcontent>◼ This should also be separate.</pcontent>
    </page>
    <page>
        <title>Content:<title>
        <content>This is the third content. Third content continues. End content three.<content>
        <paragraph>Paragraph:<paragraph>
        <pcontent>◼ Beginning of third Paragraph. End of third Paragraph.</pcontent>
        <pcontent>◼ And again a new line.</pcontent>
    </page> 
</root>
```

Comment: Can you say if you can use XSLT 2.0 here. It would be much easier with that. Thanks!

Comment: Sure, XSLT 2.0 is perfectly fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure of the exact logic required, but you probably want to use `xsl:for-each-group` here.

So, start off by selecting the `p` elements, grouping them by the ones that end in a colon

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="p" group-starting-with="p[ends-with(., ':')]">
```

Then, you can process the group using `current-group()`. However, more work is required for paragraphs, as you need a nested `xsl:for-each` to handle those starting with that funny symbol.

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="current-group() except ." group-starting-with="p[starts-with(., '◼')]">
```

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

  <xsl:template match="div[@class='page']">
    <page>
      <xsl:for-each-group select="p" group-starting-with="p[ends-with(., ':')]">
        <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test=". = 'Content:'">
            <title><xsl:value-of select="." /></title>
            <content>
              <xsl:value-of select="current-group() except ." separator="" />
            </content>
          </xsl:when>
          <xsl:when test=". = 'Paragraph:'">
            <paragraph><xsl:value-of select="." /></paragraph>
            <xsl:for-each-group select="current-group() except ." group-starting-with="p[starts-with(., '◼')]">
              <pcontent>
                <xsl:value-of select="current-group()" separator="" />
              </pcontent>
            </xsl:for-each-group>
          </xsl:when>
        </xsl:choose>
      </xsl:for-each-group>
    </page>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```